# How to localize syntax errors in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a trick to localize syntax errors? I occasionally run into this situation when editing existing code. Here's a latest example, do you see an efficient way to find the error? (I found the error already, but not efficiently)

http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/syntax-error.nb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be, I am missing something, but in your example it was quite easy: once I put your code into a notebook and tried to run, the usual orange bracket appeared, and when you expand the messages, it states very clearly that the problem was in an empty parentheses in your `vertexFormula` function. In my experience, most of the time, the orange box gives enough hints.

Another great way which I use on a daily basis it through the code highlighting in Workbench. It immediately highlights syntax errors, plus you have a very powerful Eclipse-based navigation both for a single package and multiple packages. It might seem as you lose some flexibility by going to Workbench from an interactive FrontEnd development, but I found the opposite (or may be this is the revenge of my enterprise Java background): you still can have your notebook(s) in a Workbench project, where you do the initial development, but then they get attached to the project and a number of packages that you already developed and use. The transition from notebook to a package could not be easier, since you can continue use that notebook after you transfer the code into a package, and you don't even have to worry about loading the package, as long as you do it just once inside a project.  Overall, I find the Workbench - based development much more fun as soon as your project goes over some critical mass (I'd say, perhaps around 1000 loc, but ymmv). But, complete new and independent chunks of functionality I still prefer to prototype entirely in the FrontEnd.

If you adhere to some specific coding standards in your code, or work with code which does, you might be able to develop some simple partial parser which at least breaks the code into complete chunks (function defenitions, Module-s etc, CompoundExpressions). Then, you could use ToExpression (say, Map it on a list of string code chunks returned by your partial parser), to see which piece of code is problematic (it will return $Failed on it). But if you use Workbench, this is unnecessary altogether.

Comment: ohhh, it scrolled off my message window, so all I saw was the message "Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed ."

Comment: Thanks for the input on workbench: I've been pondering whether to go that way for a while, but don't know anybody who has any experience with it. Good to hear that it works :)